# Listunspent does not return all utxos

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-cli, listunspent

I am using Bitcoin Core to get all UTXOs for watchonly imported addresses. The strategy is the following:

1. I load a new wallet

   ```py
   await client.execute("loadwallet", ["testwallet"])
   ```
2. I import multiple addresses in the loaded wallet

   ```py
   import csv
   import time

   addresses = []
   with open("addr.csv") as f:
       reader = csv.DictReader(f)
       for row in reader:
           timestamp = time.mktime(
               time.strptime(row["created_at"], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
           )
           addresses.append(
               {
                   "scriptPubKey": {"address": row["address"]},
                   "timestamp": int(timestamp),
                   "watchonly": True,
               }
           )
   res = await client.execute("importmulti", [addresses])
   print(res)
   ```

After doing that, when calculating the utxos for one of the loaded addresses, I get a list with not all the utxos that I can find a block explorer. Could you please provide insights about what is going on here and how to solve it, preferably without heavy lifting such as indexing the blockchain ?

Comment: The documentation there is not so clear, at least for me (https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/scantxoutset.html?highlight=set). I tried with something like: " bitcoin-cli scantxoutset "start" ["tb1...", "tb1...", ...] " and ti doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The documentation there is outdated. Use `bitcoin-cli help scantxoutset`. Nevertheless it still mentions what descriptor is to be used for an address: `addr(tb1...)`.

Comment: Well, it works. But with a minus. It seems that it just read the actual blockchain and returns once the right answer. Then when I check balance thereafter (using listunspent), I still get the first result which was incomplete.

Comment: This is a replacement for listunspent. It reads the UTxO set directly, not the chain.

Comment: I get it, but it is significantly slower. I took me 10 sec to scan for one address. And it's still marked experimental. Is it definitive (in other words, is the doc outdated in this regard) ?